# Sci-fi short story about beautifying technology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There's a story (or *Twilight Zone* episode) where there's a technology that can make everyone beautiful. The story is about a musician who chooses not to and becomes an outcast.

It wasn't Scott Westerfeld's *Uglies* series.

Comment: Hi, Kit! This question could be improved by looking at [this awesome guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999)! Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: If I only knew more about it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree it wasn't a question that could help me zero in on an answer without a lot of guessing what the asker meant.

But [Number 12 Looks Just Like You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_12_Looks_Just_Like_You)

is a Twilight Zone story in which everyone, once reaching late teenage, is required to be made over into a beautiful body. There are only a few models to choose from.

This is *not* optional, and *not* changes you choose, like a nose job.

While most people are brainwashed enough to want it as a rite of adult passage, one girl, the protagonist, fights it.

She loses.

Although she chooses not to, she is not a musician that I remember, and, unfortunately, not an outcast.
Because she was *forced* by a combination of trickery and hypnosis to undergo the procedure.
The brainwashing that the procedure brings on has her original rebellious personality completely washed out; now she is happy that she looks just like her "friend" who helped others to force her into it.

If that isn't a match, then refine your question.